# Structure alignment for 64-bit Windows application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, 32bit-64bit, porting

Please suggest, If we are porting 32- bit application to 64-bit in VS2010, Is it necessary to align structure at 8 byte boundary?
My application has built on VC++, MFC, COM, Win32 APIs, Custom APIs and using 3rd party libraries.
In VS2010 we have set Structure member alignment to 8 bytes (C/C++->Code generation). To fix few issues related to buffer overflow I have used #pragma pack(push, 8) but I am not sure whether it should be push 8 bytes or 4bytes.

Comment: What structures? Why do you think this is required? The compiler cares about this normally. https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/data-alignment-when-migrating-to-64-bit-intel-architecture

Comment: If `#pragma pack` ever fixed any `issues related to buffer overflow` then you have worse issues in the code to worry about. The default packing is 8 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1(v=vs.100).aspx regardless of bitness, and there is no good reason to mess with it except in very special cases.